# Are sub queries the only way I can use query data for new queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

Using the definition of sub queries as specified by http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sub-queries.htm

I'm going to get data from my first three tables, and I'll use it to query other tables.  This will happen again twice to get to the data the user needs.  I tried searching on google "How to use queries to write queries in SQL" or "How to use data returned from table to query another table?".  However, not exactly getting the information I need.  Perhaps I'm missing something or asking the wrong question.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking, try being more specific. It sounds like  you'll want to take a look at [joins](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-joins.htm)

Comment: Are you writing a script? If so, you can simply save query results to an array for later use

Comment: I've looked at this link for joins http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins, it provides a great explanation.  And yes, I'm writing a script with PHP, can I save the results of a query on PHP and use it to make another query? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but depending on what you're trying to accomplish, subqueries may be much more efficient. Can you provide pseudocode or more details?

Comment: Yes, added a link to the database schema.  I will query universities and majors table, then I'll get the prospective uni course ID's from the degree req and the gened req table.  At the same time, I query the cc_couses table to get the cc_course IDs.  Then I'll match up the cc_course IDs with the uni_course IDs from the equivalency table.  The user will see information for all the matched uni courses from the uni_courses table.  Lengthy, I apologize, but that is the query I have to do from my entire database.  Wondering, how I can go from query to query?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for joins after all

Comment: haha, am I now? If that's the case, I'll look into joins further.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: no problem! Let me know if you run into trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [joins](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-joins.htm).

**Example:**

```
SELECT * FROM cc_courses 
JOIN equivalencies
ON cc_courses.id = equivalencies.cc_course_id
JOIN uni_courses
ON equivalencies.uni_course_id = uni_courses.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I was looking for Joins after all.